# InvalidClassException: cannot bind non-enum descriptor to an enum class

Tags: java, deserialization

I am getting below mentioned error.

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: cannot bind non-enum descriptor to an enum class
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:604)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1829)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
```

I think the issue is due a class which was changed to enum sometime back. Due to that we are getting the above exception while deserializing the object.
Is there any way we can handle it ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: not really.

That is the big problem with Java enums. When you serialize them directly, you open yourself for all kinds of versioning issues.

And there isn't a nice way around this: as soon as an ObjectOutputStream encounters such kinds of problems, the stream itself is in some sort of error state. It is not possible to catch such exceptions, and to then continue to read from the same stream.

In other words: if your object stream only contains an instance of said enum class, then you can try/catch, and "ignore" the issue. But if you are de-serializing multiple values, there is no way to "skip" that enum instance and to continue with later objects in the stream.

We learned that the hard way to. Our solution was to introduce our own enum wrapper class. That class serializes the enum class, and the enum constant as *string* objects. And has special code to *rebuild* enum instances when de-serializing (and taking care of potential versioning conflicts). And instead of (de)serializing enums, we now serialize such enum wrapper instances.

Some more details... An enum constant can easily be represented with two strings: the name of the enum class, and simply the enum constant as plain string. When de-serializing, you can use that class name and enum constant string as input to [Enum.valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)). You can either put a try/catch around that call, and simply catch all errors, or you can add more smarts by first checking:

- is the de-serialized class name known, and points to an enum class
- if so: is the de-serialized enum constant string known, and supported by the corresponding enum class

Comment: Can you please give an example of the special code you used to rebuild the enum ?

Comment: @DeepakPandey Unfortunately we are talking about a few hundred lines of proprietary, non open source code here. I can't disclose a single character of that. But I will add another paragraph in my answer to outline what we did.